# Can I modify a passed method parameter

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

my gut feeling says I shouldn't do the following. I don't get any warnings about it.

```
void test(DateTime d)
{
 d = d.AddDays(2);
//do some thing with d
 }
```

or is this more proper

```
 void test(DateTime d)
 {
 DateTime _d = d.AddDays(1);
//do some thing with _d
 }
```

For some reason I have always handled passed parameters like in the second example.
But I am not sure if it's really nessesry...maybe it's just unnessary code.

I am not thinking that the calling method would be using the modified value.
anyone have any opinions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Changes to the *value of a parameter* are invisible to the caller, unless it's a `ref` or `out` parameter.

That's *not* the case if you make a change to an reference type object *referred to* by a parameter. For example:

```
public void Foo(StringBuilder b)
{
    // Changes the value of the parameter (b) - not seen by caller
    b = new StringBuilder();
}

public void Bar(StringBuilder b)
{
    // Changes the contents of the StringBuilder referred to by b's value -
    // this will be seen by the caller
    b.Append("Hello");
}
```

Finally, if the parameter is passed by reference, the change *is* seen:

```
public void Baz(ref StringBuilder b)
{
    // This change *will* be seen
    b = new StringBuilder();
}
```

For more on this, see my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can change it but the change will not go back to the caller.

If it is a **ValueType** -> The **copy** of object is sent

If it is a **RefernceType** -> **Copy** of Object reference will be sent by value. In this way properties of the object can be changed but not the reference itself - caller will not see the change anyway.

If it is sent `ref` -> Reference can be changed.

In C++ you can use `const` to prevent the change but C# does not have that. This is only to prevent the programmer by mistake try to change it - depending where the `const` is used.

Comment: That depends on details. In this very specific example, since DateTime is a struct, and has value semantics, that's true. Other arguments, with reference semantics, would reflect that change back to the caller.

Comment: @Harper: Not if the OP changes the value of the parameter, rather than making a change in the object *referred to* by the value of the parameter. See my answer for an example of the difference between these two.

Comment: @Harper, `foo = ...` will not reflect at the call site for struct or class *unless* it is specifically a `ref` (or `out`) parameter. What you do *to the members of the reference type* will reflect, what you do *to the reference itself* will not.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: OK, I left off the third option. And people think C++ is confusing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the original value, use the second method.

If you don't care about the original value, you can use either one (I'd probably still use the second though).

Either way, you're not going to hurt anybody else's values (even if you re-assign the value, it won't make it back to the caller) in this case.