# A void method that takes an IQueryable<T> and modifies it doesn't seem to persist the modifications

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have a method:

```
public void ExterminateCuddlyKittens(IQueryable<Kitten> data)
{
    data = data.Where(c => !c.Cuddly);
}
```

It takes in some kittens and removes any that don't have `Cuddly = true`.

I tested this method with this code:

```
List<Kitten> myKittens = new List<Kitten>();
myKittens.Add(new Kitten() { Cuddly = true; });

ExterminateCuddlyKittens(myKittens.AsQueryable());

Assert.AreEqual(0, myKittens.Count);
```

When debugging my method, intellisense shows that it correctly exterminates the kitten, and I have an empty collection at the end of the method.

However, once we're back in the test, myKittens still has a count of 1, and the kitten has escaped extermination.

I am not sure why, as `data` is a reference, isn't it? So modifying the collection I would expect to persist. However I am not sure if `AsQueryable` is creating a copy or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is because you´re passing the collection by value. Thus any changes to it made by *re-referencoing it* are lost when you´re out of the method. You´d need the `ref`-keyword for this. However I guess you shouldn´t do that on an `IQueryable`. E.g. have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991022/can-i-modify-a-passed-method-parameter

Comment: Your method should return `IQueryable<Kitten>`.  Your method modifies something that you want outside of the scope of the method.  You **need** to return it.  (I know you could use out variables, or pass by ref, but both of those options are typically a bad idea).

Comment: `you´re passing the collection by value` you're passing the reference to the IQueryable by value...not the collection itself.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: there's no reason not to use an iqueryable as a ref or out parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"So modifying the collection I would expect to persist."

The thing is you haven't modified the collection. `data.Where(c => !c.Cuddly)` doesn't modify data. It returns a new object based on data. You seem to have this idea in mind since you do this:

```
data = data.Where(c => !c.Cuddly);
```

The thing is this also doesn't modify the object passed into the method. `data` is like a box holding an object. What you have done is taken the original `data` out of the box and put a different one in. When you return from the method though the parent method still has the original unmodified version of `data`.

You should return a `IQueryable<Kitten>` from your method and assign it appropriately.

Comment: I see. I realise why I was so confused, it's because I am using entity framework. It doesn't like me calling a method to do filtering as it tries to translate it into SQL. Hmm. More research needed. Thanks though.

Comment: EF should be fine with filtering with your method.  Its still using LINQ to query...

Comment: The call to the method that applies the filtering doesn't work because it tries to convert it into SQL, which is impossible. I'm not sure how to get around that. I can possibly call it in advance of my EF code and get it to return a Func and then apply that.

Comment: @NibblyPig: I'm a little confused as to how you are making the call. If you have an `IQueryable` and you were to do `queryable = Exterminate(queryable)` then nothing should be trying to translate the call to `Exterminate` to SQL. if you do something like `queryable = queryable.Where(x=>!ShouldIExterminate(x))` then in this case you'd have problems because it would want to translate `ShouldIExterminate` but this isn't what you seem to be doing in your example...

Comment: Ah yeah, it is because I am doing it inside a Where.